# How can i convert booleans from dataframe to integers?

Tags: python, pandas

I had a task to create new variables in dataset with specific values. The problem is that new column 'Alone' has bool values as a result and i cant combine them with integer to find out necessary value

```
filt = titset['Survived'] == 1
for i, row in titset.iterrows():
titset.loc[i, 'Family_size'] = row['Parch'] + row['SibSp']
titset.loc[i, 'Alone'] = 0 if row['Parch'] + row['SibSp'] > 0 else 1

fi1 = titset[titset['Family_size']==0]
tf = titset['PassengerId'].loc[filt & fi1].count()
tf
```

Photo of my dataset if necessary [DATAFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh4Oe.png)

Comment: Why not?   Boolean values can participate in integer expressions.  True is 1, and False is 0.

Comment: I  get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'float'

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use loops with pandas, you can do the same much faster with vectorised operations:

```
titset['Family_size'] = titset['Parch'] + titset['SibSp']
titset['Alone'] = (~(titset['Parch'] + titset['SibSp']) > 0).astype(int)
```

In order to convert boolean to integer you can use `titset['Alone'] = titset['Alone'].astype(int)`